# C++ implementation of a Cache Replacement Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, caching, lru

**Context:** As part of an assignment, I am required to think of a new cache replacement algorithm. There are a number of such algorithms like Least Recently Used, First In First Out, but I am not allowed to use any of those. So I have thought of a new algorithm which works according to index. The index will start at 0 and go on until the n-1 where n is the size of the cache.

If the cache is not full, I put items at index 0,1,2,...,n-1 until it is full. After the cache is full, I just replace the blocks at index(th) index of the cache block (represented as array in this case.)

**Problem:**
After seeing the code you will realize that it is quite simple as I am just adding elements to key and value of my array and increasing size of the array. If the array gets full, I am replacing the index(th) element by the new item and increasing index so that I will replace the next block/ index in upcoming iterations

But the problem is that while inserting items, the same elements are being put at index=0 and I am having very difficult time figuring out why. Any helps will be highly appreciated.

In conclusion,

```
//This is the faulty output
/*
*****---Executing print function---*****

Block 0 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 1 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 2 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 3 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
*/

//While it should have been
/*
 Block 0 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
 Block 1 Memory Address: 10011 Value: 11
 Block 2 Memory Address: 10100 Value: 12
 Block 3 Memory Address: 10101 Value: 13
 */
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//We will have 2 primary functions. get(key) and set(key, value).
//get is used to retreive the value if key exists in cache. Otherwise it will return -1.
//set is used to set (key,value) by replacing the block. if value is already existent it should not do anything.
//Using this struct, we will add key value and a data structure for holding a pair of key and value.
typedef struct
{
    int key, value; //to store address and data
}cache_set;

class algorithm_implement
{
public:
    cache_set* cache;//array to hold information
    int capacity; //number of blocks per set
    int size; //total current elements in the cache
    int index;

    algorithm_implement(int total_size)
    {
        cache = new cache_set[capacity];
        size = 0;
        capacity = total_size;
        index = 0;
    }
    int get (int mem_address)
    {
        //if the cache already has the address in it then retreive the value and do nothing. Else return -1
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++ )
        {
            if (cache[i].key == mem_address)
            {
                int req_val = cache[i].value;
                return req_val;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    void set(int mem_address, int data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< capacity; i++){
            if (cache[i].key == mem_address)
            {
                cout << "This memory address is already present in the cache. No replacement necessary."<<endl<<endl;
                return;
            }
            //if item is not present and blocks are full then put key and value at index(th) position and increment the index. Don't let index be greater than capacity.
            if (size == capacity)
            {
                index = index % capacity;
                cache[index].key = mem_address;
                cache[index].value = data;
                index ++;

            }
            //if item is not present and some blocks are empty then put key and value at the index of size and increment size until cache is full.
            else if (size < capacity)
            {
                cache[size].key = mem_address;
                cache[size].value = data;
                size ++;
            }
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "*****---Executing print function---*****"<<endl<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i< capacity; i++)
        {
            cout << "Block "<< i << " Memory Address: "<<cache[i].key << " Value: "<<cache[i].value<<endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    int num_blocks = 4;
    algorithm_implement index_based = *new algorithm_implement(num_blocks);
    index_based.set(10010, 10);
    index_based.set(10011, 11);
    index_based.set(10100, 12);
    index_based.set(10101, 13);
    //Trying to put pre-existing element in the cache.
    index_based.set(10010, 10);
    //Printing the elements present in the cache
    index_based.print();
}
//This is the output
/*
*****---Executing print function---*****

Block 0 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 1 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 2 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
Block 3 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
*/

//The output should have been
/*
 Block 0 Memory Address: 10010 Value: 10
 Block 1 Memory Address: 10011 Value: 11
 Block 2 Memory Address: 10100 Value: 12
 Block 3 Memory Address: 10101 Value: 13
 */
```

Comment: In the constructor, the `capacity` is being used to allocate the array before it is assigned with `total_size`.  I would assume it can lead to a segmentation fault if the value in there before the assignment is less than `total_size`, and to a waste of allocated memory, but I can't see how it would lead to this behaviour.